# Unable to filter the non empty array data using lodash filter

Tags: javascript, lodash

An array is as follows :

```
    const arr = [ { name: 'Aditya', hobbies: ['Football', 'Basketball'] }, 
                  { name: 'Amitabh', hobbies: [] },
                  { name: 'Akhsara', hobbies: ['Basketball'] },
                  { name: 'Aia', hobbies: [] }
                ];
```

Using filter function as follows:

```
     public getDatas(hobby) {        
      const data =  _.filter(arr, {hobbies : hobby === 'Unclear' : [] ? [hobby]} );     
    }
```

I have some how set the `Unclear` hobbies to empty arrays, when it is `Unclear` then it is **NOT** returning me the data with `hobbies : []` instead it is returning me the whole of **arr**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicate (second argument) of `_.filter` indicates the property or properties to filter. Since `hobbies` is a string array, there is no `hobby` property of `hobbies`.

You can use [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) like this:

```js
const data = _.filter(arr, item => item.hobbies.includes('Unclear'));

// If you want to extract just the 'hobbies' object, not the parent
const hobbies = _.map(data, 'hobbies');
```