# How can I group by the array using lodash or javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

An Array is as follows:

```
let names = [
             'Aditya',
             'Aditya',
             'Aditya',
             'Abhi',
             'Abhi',
             'goyal'
            ]
```

I want to use lodash function and convert the **names** array which will return me as

```
[
  Aditya(3),
  Abhi(2),
  goyal(1)
]
```

Comment: What's that output meant to be, an array of functions? Or did you mean `[ 'Aditya(3)', 'Abhi(2)', 'goyal(1)']`?

Comment: yes its an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) [`_.countBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#countBy) the names to produce an object with name/count as the key/value.

2) Use [`_.entries`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#toPairs) to convert the object to a set of nest entry arrays.

3) [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map) over the entries to produce the required output.

```js
const names = ["Aditya","Aditya","Aditya","Abhi","Abhi","goyal"]

const toString = ([name, count]) => `${name}(${count})`;
const entries = _.entries(_.countBy(names));
const result = _.map(entries, toString);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Alternatively you can use vanilla JS to achieve the same thing in (almost) the same amount of code using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const names = ["Aditya","Aditya","Aditya","Abhi","Abhi","goyal"]

const counts = names.reduce((acc, c) => {
  return acc[c] = (acc[c] || 0) + 1, acc;
}, {});

const toString = ([name, count]) => `${name}(${count})`;
const entries = Object.entries(counts);
const result2 = entries.map(toString);

console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `_.countBy()` to get an object of names with count, or a `_.groupBy()` if you want an object of names with arrays.

An array of arrays using `_.groupBy()` and `_.values()`:

```js
const names = ["Aditya","Aditya","Aditya","Abhi","Abhi","goyal"]

const result = _.values(_.groupBy(names))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

And object of counts with `_.countBy`:

```js
const names = ["Aditya","Aditya","Aditya","Abhi","Abhi","goyal"]

const result = _.countBy(names)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Update - to get an array of strings that combine the key and value, you can use `_.countBy()`, and then `_.map()` it (lodash's `_.map()` works on objects as well).

```js
const names = ["Aditya","Aditya","Aditya","Abhi","Abhi","goyal"]

const result = _.map(_.countBy(names), (v, k) => `${k}(${v})`)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey if you can answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53856633/unable-to-filter-the-non-empty-array-data-using-lodash-filter